# gzip don't work on images

Tags: regex, nginx

I use nginx + puma.
I have a special folder where users can download images, so I what enable gzip on them. But when i chek browser. there is no Content-Encoding:gzip header in respond.
Probably fail in reg ex:

```
  location ^~ /media/gallery/.*/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|mp3|ogg|gz|swf)$ {
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 3;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  add_header Last-Modified "";
  add_header ETag "";
  break;
}
```

PS folders look like:

site.com/media/gallery/1/test_image.jpg

site.com/media/gallery/1/other_image.png

site.com/media/gallery/4/other_folder_image.jpg

**Update:**
[image_from_dev_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAe2C.jpg)

Comment: The [regex looks fine](https://regex101.com/r/Z1Jt8h/1).

Comment: I suspect something in the process knows that PNG is already compressed and so gzip won't do anything useful there anyway.  Not a programming question anyhow; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tripleee I put screenshot just for showing headers. There is no gzip encode with jpg and other images.

Comment: @tripleee oh. now i get what you mean thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the nginx directive `gzip_types` which you can pass mimetypes to. Default is text/html

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html

!! Tho I have to tell that compressing any non-text files with gzip on the fly will cause high overhead (CPU especially) for both, the server and the client with low to no bandwidth savings.

What you are looking for is an image compression like mozjpeg which compresses jpeg files efficiently without loss of quality